# Pergunta marcada como ampla mas é simples

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento, perguntas-amplas

Recentemente participei dessa questão: [Carregar lista por partes utilizando AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98436/carregar-lista-por-partes-utilizando-angularjs)

Que acabou sendo marcada como "Ampla", porém tem uma solução bem simples, inclusive foi a minha resposta.

O que podemos fazer nesse caso? Ou realmente essa pergunta é 'ampla' para receber a sinalização?

Comment: Não entendo o suficiente de Angular pra poder julgar bem o suficiente, mas se a pergunta consegue ter uma resposta boa, de alta qualidade, aceita pelo autor, concordo que é um indicativo enorme de que não é ampla demais.

Comment: Pois é, e acabou sendo aceita. Isso que achei estranho. Mas não sei como proceder nem julgar ela como ampla ou não.

Comment: "Ampla Demais" é para casos que a pergunta é muito abrangente, e que a resposta acabaria tocando em diversos problemas diferentes, ou teria que ser enorme, para poder solucionar o problema. Se você conseguiu responder corretamente com 3 parágrafos e 1 trecho de código, não vejo porque ela seria ampla demais.

Comment: Mas, o que pode ser feito nesse caso?

Comment: A pergunta pode ser reaberta, sem problemas. Mas seria bom ter mais gente - de preferência com alguma experiência em Angular - participando da discussão aqui, antes de tomarmos qualquer atitude.

Comment: Também não acredito que seja ampla demais. (ps: tenho conhecimento de angular)